# How to join a table multiple times?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I'm trying to achieve this result, "places" table contains 3 types of places (state, city, slaughter). I want to show them as different columns based on "type" which is an enum column.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT sifs.sif_id, places.`name` as city FROM sifs
INNER JOIN places ON sifs.city_id = places.id
union all
SELECT sifs.sif_id, places.`name` as slaughter FROM sifs
INNER JOIN places ON sifs.slaughter_id = places.id
union all
SELECT sifs.sif_id, places.`name` as state FROM sifs
INNER JOIN places ON sifs.state_id = places.id
```

here's query result:

```
sif_id | city
15     | Pedro Juan Caballero(PRY)
15     | FRIGONORTE
15     | Amambay(PRY)
```

here's what I want:

```
sif_id | state       | city                     | slaughter
15     | Amambay(PRY)| Pedro Juan Caballero(PRY)| FRIGONORTE
```

tables fields:

sifs: sif_id, state_id, city_id, slaughter_id
places: name, type('state', 'city', 'slaughter')

Comment: What is the issue with your query?  What results do you want?  What does your data look like?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've edited the question and accepted your answer. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want multiple `join`s:

```
SELECT s.sif_id, pc.name as city, ps.name as slaughter,
       pst.name as state
FROM sifs s LEFT JOIN
     places pc
     ON s.city_id = pc.id LEFT JOIN
     places ps
     ON s.slaughter_id = ps.id LEFT JOIN
     places pss
     ON s.state_id = pst.id;
```

This uses `LEFT JOIN` so all rows in `sifs` are in the result set, even if some ids have no matches.